# Makefile: expand dependencies

Tags: c, string, function, makefile

First off, the title is very generic because there are just tons of ways of how to possibly solve this. However, I'm looking for a **clean** and neat way.

Situation:
I have two equal object files `foo.o` and `foo-pi.o`, the latter of which is position-independent (compiled with `-fPIC`). Both depend on `foo.h` and `bar.h`.

Problem:
How do I, without code duplication, declare dependency of all `foo*.o` to `bar.h`?

Solutions so far:
`$(shell bash -c 'echo -ne foo{-pi,}.o'): bar.h`
`$(addsuffix .o, $(addprefix fo, o-pi o)): bar.h`
`foo.o foo-pi.o: bar.h`

The first solution is not portable on systems that don't support `bash`, the second is a dirty solution since I could not figure out how to use empty strings in `addprefix`. The third solution includes duplicate mention of `foo` which I want to avoid.

Comment: Rather than using renaming to distinguish PIC vs non-PIC code, consider putting the two types of objects in different subdirectories (`obj/` and `obj.PIC/` for example), and leaving the names the same. That might make a lot of what you're trying to do easier...

Comment: True, but the specification does not permit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to use `echo -en` because the shell function always strips off the trailing newline, just like backticks in the shell.  However, even if you did need to omit trailing newlines you can use the `printf` program instead of `echo`: `printf` is far more portable and reliable than passing options to `echo`, which are different everywhere.

Second, you can use the foreach function rather than the gross addsuffix/addprefix.  The problem you're having is that you're trying to turn one word into two words, and those functions (as well as the more generic ones like patsubst) just don't do that.  Try: `$(foreach F,foo,$F $F-pi.o): dep.h`

Third, I personally would just write it out since it's less effort and more easily readable.